# Program segfaulting based only on printf statements

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, printf, kernighan-and-ritchie

In doing a K&R exercise, I'm encountering a behavior that I can't make any sense of and for which I can't find any solutions here on SOF:

The program (converting base 10 ints to base *n* strings) runs fine with my extra `printf()` statements. As soon as I begin removing or commenting them out, the unexpected behavior begins

The code in full:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

char numtochar(unsigned n);
void reverse(char s[]);
void itob(int n, char s[], unsigned b);

int main() {
    // test numtochar
    assert(numtochar(1) == '1');
    assert(numtochar(11) == 'b');
    assert(numtochar(61) == 'Z');
    assert(numtochar(62) == '+');
    // test reverse
    char t[] = "TestiNg";
    reverse(t);
    assert(!strcmp(t, "gNitseT"));
    // test itob
    printf("if this is commented out, it will segfault\n");
    char s[MAXLINE];
    itob(10, s, 10);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    assert(strcmp(s, "10") == 0);
    itob(11, s, 2);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    assert(strcmp(s, "1011") == 0);
    itob(100, s, 8);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    assert(strcmp(s, "144") == 0);
    itob(1337, s, 32);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    assert(strcmp(s, "19p") == 0);
    itob(127, s, 64);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    assert(strcmp(s, "1/") == 0);
    return 0;
}

/* This numbering is not standard base-64, but will be consistent so long
 * as base <= 64
 * 0..63 => 0..9a..zA..Z+/
 */
char numtochar(unsigned n) {
    assert(n < 64);
    if (n < 10)
        return ('0' + n);
    else if (n >= 10 && n < 36)
        return ('a' + (n - 10));
    else if (n >= 36 && n < 62)
        return ('A' + (n - 36));
    else if (n == 62)
        return '+';
    else if (n == 63)
        return '/';
}

void reverse(char s[]) {
    int c, i, j;
    for (i=0, j=strlen(s)-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
    return;
}

void itob(int n, char s[], unsigned b) {
    assert(b <= 64);
    int c, i, sign;
    if ((sign = n) < 0)
        n = -n;
    do {
        s[i++] = numtochar(n % b);
    } while ((n /= b) != 0);
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
    return;
}
```

As demonstrated below, if I run with all the printf statements, it runs as expected. If I comment out the first statement, it will run fine once but not again.

```
user@laptop:~/git/ansi_c/ch3 $ make ex05.o # no printf statements commented
gcc -o ex05.o ex05.c
user@laptop:~/git/ansi_c/ch3 $ ./ex05.o
if this is commented out, it will segfault
10
1011
144
19p
1/
user@laptop:~/git/ansi_c/ch3 $ make ex05.o # comment out first printf statement
gcc -o ex05.o ex05.c
user@laptop:~/git/ansi_c/ch3 $ ./ex05.o
10
1011
144
19p
1/
user@laptop:~/git/ansi_c/ch3 $ make ex05.o # resave after no changes
gcc -o ex05.o ex05.c
user@laptop:~/git/ansi_c/ch3 $ ./ex05.o
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If however I uncomment out the first printf statement and comment out the second one (`printf("%s\n", s);`), the result of itob is no longer passing the assert statement.

```
user@laptop:~/git/ansi_c/ch3 $ make ex05.o # uncomment first printf, comment second
gcc -o ex05.o ex05.c
user@laptop:~/git/ansi_c/ch3 $ ./ex05.o
if this is commented out, it will segfault
101101
ex05.o: ex05.c:33: main: Assertion `strcmp(s, "1011") == 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

gcc version is 7.2.1

If I remove all printf statements it also segfaults. Being new to C, I am unsure where I could be underallocating memory if that is indeed the problem, as all similar questions I saw revolved around use of malloc.

Comment: It seems the time had come to learn how to use a debugger. Also you might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Werror`. Your compiler should be complaining about your use of `i` in `itob()`.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important thing to learn in C, is that if you don't initialise a variable with a value and then access it, it will lead to undefined behaviour. Take this function for example...

```
void itob(int n, char s[], unsigned b) {
    assert(b <= 64);
    int c, i, sign;
    if ((sign = n) < 0)
        n = -n;
    do {
        s[i++] = numtochar(n % b);
    } while ((n /= b) != 0);
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
    return;
}
```

What value does `i` have at the start? It might be 0, but what it'll actually be is whatever random value happened to be in memory at the time. Which is why un-commenting code changes things as it's affecting what the value of `i` has.

Just changing it to start with the value 0 fixes your problem. Also removed `c` as it's not used

```
int i = 0, sign;
```

A good tool to use is `valgrind` - it will tell you where memory corruption and leaks occur.

Comment: I had tried using `valgrind` based on other questions but I had not understood what the message `Use of uninitialised value of size 8` had been referring to. I can see the oversight now.

Answer (score 0):

running `gdb` on the posted code results in:

Note: ``untitled2` is the name I gave your program.

```
gdb untitled2

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from untitled2...done.

(gdb) br main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4008e1: file untitled2.c, line 12.

(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/rkwill/Documents/forum/untitled2 

Breakpoint 1, main () at untitled2.c:12
12  {

(gdb) c
Continuing.
if this is commented out, it will segfault

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400d2a in itob (n=10, s=0x7fffffffda80 "\264\332\377\377\377\177", 
    b=10) at untitled2.c:103
103         s[i++] = numtochar(n % b);
(gdb)
```

which is in this code block:

```
do
{
    s[i++] = numtochar(n % b);
} while ((n /= b) != 0);
```

the main problem is using the local variable `i` with out it being initialized (so it contains what ever trash was on the stack at the location of the variable.)

in other words, the program contains some undefined behavior and that is what caused the seg fault.